# A-frame animation to value and back

Tags: html, animation, aframe

I am currently working with a-frame for the first time and can't figure out how to animate back to the starting point again. Currently I have an arm rotating 90 degrees and when it has done that it snaps back to it's original position. How can I make it so that the animation goes from 0 degrees to 90 degrees and back.

```
<a-obj-model src="#robot" mtl="#material" position="0 0 -150">
</a-obj-model>
<a-obj-model src="#robotshoulder" mtl="#material" position="0 0 -150">
    <a-animation attribute="rotation"
        dur="3000"
        fill="both"
        from="0 0 0"
        to="90 0 0"
        repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
    <a-obj-model src="#robotarmr" mtl="#material">
    </a-obj-model>
</a-obj-model>
```

Thanks for the help already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using direction="alternate" in your animation properties.

From the A-Frame docs:

> The direction attribute defines which way to animate between the starting value and the final value.
>   When we define an alternating direction, the animation will go back and forth between the from and to values like a yo-yo. Alternating directions only take affect when we repeat the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I gave it a try, but for some reason that didn't change anything.

Comment: Oh, then try removing the fill attribute and see if that works. I can't test it right now, sorry. I think it interfers with your desired behaviour. From A-Frame: backwards  Before the animation starts, set the starting value to the from value.
both  Combine the effects of both backwards fill and forwards fill.
forwards  After the animation finishes, the final value will stay at the to value. The default fill.

Comment: Thas was the issue indeed! Thank you very much.

Comment: note that now as of 24th of August 2023, direction is replace with dir

Comment: I had to combine it with this @QuincyNorbert
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51050251/8094047